# Binary Quadratic Form: Prove Two Forms are Equivalent

Tags: matrices, number-theory, quadratic-forms, binary

Given two binary quadratic forms f and g which have the same determinant and represent the same prime p, show that f and g are equivalent (related by a 2*2 matrix of determinant 1 or -1).

My approach: Obviously f and g properly represent p. Then f ~ (p,k,l) and g~(p,k',l'). Now it remains to show that (p, k, l) and (p, k', l') are related by a 2*2 matrix with det = 1 or -1. (thus not necessarily properly equivalent; general equivalent suffices)

Any hint will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the forms are $(p,k,l)$ and $(p,n,m)$. Then 
$$k^2-4pl=n^2-4pm$$ and thus (since you dont care about improper equivalence) we may assume
$$k\equiv n\mod 2p$$

As is well known the transform
$$x\mapsto x+by$$
$$y\mapsto y$$
leaves the initial coefficient $p$ unchanged and changes the middle coefficient by $+2bp$. We are done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have been more familiar with that classic transformation.